# Query Multiple Post Types Using WP REST API V2 (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest, wp-api

I have used WordPress REST API Version 1 (V1) in the past on several websites. One feature that I used extensively was the ability to call multiple post types in a single query.

In WP REST API Version 1 I was able to use the following endpoint to get a list that contained posts from both `book` and `movie` post types:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/posts?type[]=book&type[]=movie
```

I have setup my custom post types so that they are accessible from the api and can be called like this:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/book/
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/movie/
```

What is the best way to accomplish this in WP REST API Version 2 (V2)? I have looked into custom endpoints, but I am not sure that this will be the best solution for me (http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/). There may be a dozen or so custom post types and I will need to run a dynamic query based on a user's input of what types of content they will want to see.

I am open to ideas or advice if anyone has tackled a similar problem before.

Thanks everyone!

**Update:**

I have been told in the WP-API issues forum that this is not possible in V2: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2567

This does not make sense to me at all. In WordPress I can create a post type for `movie` and another for `book` and both can share a custom taxonomy of `genre`. Using `WP_Query`, I can query both of these post types in one loop, based on genre if I would like. Why would the REST API for WordPress not include basic functionality to query both of these at once, especially as it was working fine in V1? Without this feature I am not going to be able to update my current web applications from V1 to V2.

My question now is, has anyone successfully created an endpoint that can create this functionality?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I needed exactly the functionality you were asking for, so I made a custom endpoint. It only exposes a `WP_REST_Server::READABLE` request for multiple posts, but it seems to work pretty well.

Most of the post-type specific stuff is simply forwarded to WP_REST_Posts_Controller instances, which are instantiated for each query result. I hope this will lower the risk of compatibility issues with other plugins or future updates to the api.

Feel free to use the code below:

```
/**
 * Custom endpoint for querying for multiple post-types.
 * Mimics `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` as closely as possible.
 *
 * New filters:
 *  - `rest_multiple_post_type_query` Filters the query arguments as generated
 *    from the request parameters.
 *
 * @author Ruben Vreeken
 */
class WP_REST_MultiplePostType_Controller extends WP_REST_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->version   = '2';
        $this->namespace = 'websiteje/v' . $this->version;
        $this->rest_base = 'multiple-post-type';
    }

    /**
     * Register the routes for the objects of the controller.
     */
    public function register_routes()
    {
        register_rest_route($this->namespace, '/' . $this->rest_base, array(
            array(
                'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
                'callback'            => array($this, 'get_items'),
                'permission_callback' => array($this, 'get_items_permissions_check'),
                'args'                => $this->get_collection_params(),
            ),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Check if a given request has access to get items
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function get_items_permissions_check($request)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get a collection of items
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request  $request  Full data about the request.
     * @return WP_Error|WP_REST_Response
     */
    public function get_items($request)
    {
        $args                        = array();
        $args['author__in']          = $request['author'];
        $args['author__not_in']      = $request['author_exclude'];
        $args['menu_order']          = $request['menu_order'];
        $args['offset']              = $request['offset'];
        $args['order']               = $request['order'];
        $args['orderby']             = $request['orderby'];
        $args['paged']               = $request['page'];
        $args['post__in']            = $request['include'];
        $args['post__not_in']        = $request['exclude'];
        $args['posts_per_page']      = $request['per_page'];
        $args['name']                = $request['slug'];
        $args['post_type']           = $request['type'];
        $args['post_parent__in']     = $request['parent'];
        $args['post_parent__not_in'] = $request['parent_exclude'];
        $args['post_status']         = $request['status'];
        $args['s']                   = $request['search'];

        $args['date_query'] = array();
        // Set before into date query. Date query must be specified as an array
        // of an array.
        if (isset($request['before'])) {
            $args['date_query'][0]['before'] = $request['before'];
        }

        // Set after into date query. Date query must be specified as an array
        // of an array.
        if (isset($request['after'])) {
            $args['date_query'][0]['after'] = $request['after'];
        }

        if (is_array($request['filter'])) {
            $args = array_merge($args, $request['filter']);
            unset($args['filter']);
        }

        // Ensure array of post_types
        if (!is_array($args['post_type'])) {
            $args['post_type'] = array($args['post_type']);
        }

        /**
         * Filter the query arguments for a request.
         *
         * Enables adding extra arguments or setting defaults for a post
         * collection request.
         *
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/
         *
         * @param array            $args     Key value array of query var to query value.
         * @param WP_REST_Request  $request  The request used.
         *
         * @var Function
         */
        $args       = apply_filters("rest_multiple_post_type_query", $args, $request);
        $query_args = $this->prepare_items_query($args, $request);

        // Get taxonomies for each of the requested post_types
        $taxonomies = wp_list_filter(get_object_taxonomies($query_args['post_type'], 'objects'), array('show_in_rest' => true));

        // Construct taxonomy query
        foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
            $base = !empty($taxonomy->rest_base) ? $taxonomy->rest_base : $taxonomy->name;

            if (!empty($request[$base])) {
                $query_args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy'         => $taxonomy->name,
                    'field'            => 'term_id',
                    'terms'            => $request[$base],
                    'include_children' => false,
                );
            }
        }

        // Execute the query
        $posts_query  = new WP_Query();
        $query_result = $posts_query->query($query_args);

        // Handle query results
        $posts = array();
        foreach ($query_result as $post) {
            // Get PostController for Post Type
            $postsController = new WP_REST_Posts_Controller($post->post_type);

            if (!$postsController->check_read_permission($post)) {
                continue;
            }

            $data    = $postsController->prepare_item_for_response($post, $request);
            $posts[] = $postsController->prepare_response_for_collection($data);
        }

        // Calc total post count
        $page        = (int) $query_args['paged'];
        $total_posts = $posts_query->found_posts;

        // Out-of-bounds, run the query again without LIMIT for total count
        if ($total_posts < 1) {
            unset($query_args['paged']);
            $count_query = new WP_Query();
            $count_query->query($query_args);
            $total_posts = $count_query->found_posts;
        }

        // Calc total page count
        $max_pages = ceil($total_posts / (int) $query_args['posts_per_page']);

        // Construct response
        $response = rest_ensure_response($posts);
        $response->header('X-WP-Total', (int) $total_posts);
        $response->header('X-WP-TotalPages', (int) $max_pages);

        // Construct base url for pagination links
        $request_params = $request->get_query_params();
        if (!empty($request_params['filter'])) {
            // Normalize the pagination params.
            unset($request_params['filter']['posts_per_page']);
            unset($request_params['filter']['paged']);
        }
        $base = add_query_arg($request_params, rest_url(sprintf('/%s/%s', $this->namespace, $this->rest_base)));

        // Create link for previous page, if needed
        if ($page > 1) {
            $prev_page = $page - 1;
            if ($prev_page > $max_pages) {
                $prev_page = $max_pages;
            }
            $prev_link = add_query_arg('page', $prev_page, $base);
            $response->link_header('prev', $prev_link);
        }

        // Create link for next page, if needed
        if ($max_pages > $page) {
            $next_page = $page + 1;
            $next_link = add_query_arg('page', $next_page, $base);
            $response->link_header('next', $next_link);
        }

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Determine the allowed query_vars for a get_items() response and prepare
     * for WP_Query.
     *
     * @param  array            $prepared_args
     * @param  WP_REST_Request  $request
     *
     * @return array            $query_args
     */
    protected function prepare_items_query($prepared_args = array(), $request = null)
    {

        $valid_vars = array_flip($this->get_allowed_query_vars($request['type']));
        $query_args = array();
        foreach ($valid_vars as $var => $index) {
            if (isset($prepared_args[$var])) {
                /**
                 * Filter the query_vars used in `get_items` for the constructed
                 * query.
                 *
                 * The dynamic portion of the hook name, $var, refers to the
                 * query_var key.
                 *
                 * @param mixed  $prepared_args[  $var ] The query_var value.
                 */
                $query_args[$var] = apply_filters("rest_query_var-{$var}", $prepared_args[$var]);
            }
        }

        // Only allow sticky psts if 'post' is one of the requested post types.
        if (in_array('post', $query_args['post_type']) || !isset($query_args['ignore_sticky_posts'])) {
            $query_args['ignore_sticky_posts'] = true;
        }

        if ('include' === $query_args['orderby']) {
            $query_args['orderby'] = 'post__in';
        }

        return $query_args;
    }

    /**
     * Get all the WP Query vars that are allowed for the API request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function get_allowed_query_vars($post_types)
    {
        global $wp;
        $editPosts = true;

        /**
         * Filter the publicly allowed query vars.
         *
         * Allows adjusting of the default query vars that are made public.
         *
         * @param array  Array  of allowed WP_Query query vars.
         *
         * @var Function
         */
        $valid_vars = apply_filters('query_vars', $wp->public_query_vars);

        /**
         * We allow 'private' query vars for authorized users only.
         *
         * It the user has `edit_posts` capabilty for *every* requested post
         * type, we also allow use of private query parameters, which are only
         * undesirable on the frontend, but are safe for use in query strings.
         *
         * To disable anyway, use `add_filter( 'rest_private_query_vars',
         * '__return_empty_array' );`
         *
         * @param array  $private_query_vars  Array of allowed query vars for
         *                                    authorized users.
         *
         * @var boolean
         */
        $edit_posts = true;
        foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
            $post_type_obj = get_post_type_object($post_type);
            if (!current_user_can($post_type_obj->cap->edit_posts)) {
                $edit_posts = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($edit_posts) {
            $private    = apply_filters('rest_private_query_vars', $wp->private_query_vars);
            $valid_vars = array_merge($valid_vars, $private);
        }

        // Define our own in addition to WP's normal vars.
        $rest_valid = array(
            'author__in',
            'author__not_in',
            'ignore_sticky_posts',
            'menu_order',
            'offset',
            'post__in',
            'post__not_in',
            'post_parent',
            'post_parent__in',
            'post_parent__not_in',
            'posts_per_page',
            'date_query',
        );
        $valid_vars = array_merge($valid_vars, $rest_valid);

        /**
         * Filter allowed query vars for the REST API.
         *
         * This filter allows you to add or remove query vars from the final
         * allowed list for all requests, including unauthenticated ones. To
         * alter the vars for editors only, {@see rest_private_query_vars}.
         *
         * @param array {
         *    Array of allowed WP_Query query vars.
         *
         *    @param string $allowed_query_var The query var to allow.
         * }
         */
        $valid_vars = apply_filters('rest_query_vars', $valid_vars);

        return $valid_vars;
    }

    /**
     * Get the query params for collections of attachments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_collection_params()
    {
        $params = parent::get_collection_params();

        $params['context']['default'] = 'view';

        $params['after'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Limit response to resources published after a given ISO8601 compliant date.'),
            'type'              => 'string',
            'format'            => 'date-time',
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
        );

        $params['author'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Limit result set to posts assigned to specific authors.'),
            'type'              => 'array',
            'default'           => array(),
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_parse_id_list',
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
        );
        $params['author_exclude'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Ensure result set excludes posts assigned to specific authors.'),
            'type'              => 'array',
            'default'           => array(),
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_parse_id_list',
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
        );

        $params['before'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Limit response to resources published before a given ISO8601 compliant date.'),
            'type'              => 'string',
            'format'            => 'date-time',
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
        );
        $params['exclude'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Ensure result set excludes specific ids.'),
            'type'              => 'array',
            'default'           => array(),
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_parse_id_list',
        );
        $params['include'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Limit result set to specific ids.'),
            'type'              => 'array',
            'default'           => array(),
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_parse_id_list',
        );

        $params['menu_order'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Limit result set to resources with a specific menu_order value.'),
            'type'              => 'integer',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
        );

        $params['offset'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Offset the result set by a specific number of items.'),
            'type'              => 'integer',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
        );
        $params['order'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Order sort attribute ascending or descending.'),
            'type'              => 'string',
            'default'           => 'desc',
            'enum'              => array('asc', 'desc'),
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
        );
        $params['orderby'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Sort collection by object attribute.'),
            'type'              => 'string',
            'default'           => 'date',
            'enum'              => array(
                'date',
                'id',
                'include',
                'title',
                'slug',
            ),
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
        );

        $params['orderby']['enum'][] = 'menu_order';

        $params['parent'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Limit result set to those of particular parent ids.'),
            'type'              => 'array',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_parse_id_list',
            'default'           => array(),
        );
        $params['parent_exclude'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Limit result set to all items except those of a particular parent id.'),
            'type'              => 'array',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_parse_id_list',
            'default'           => array(),
        );

        $params['slug'] = array(
            'description'       => __('Limit result set to posts with a specific slug.'),
            'type'              => 'string',
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
        );
        $params['status'] = array(
            'default'           => 'publish',
            'description'       => __('Limit result set to posts assigned a specific status.'),
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_key',
            'type'              => 'string',
            'validate_callback' => array($this, 'validate_user_can_query_private_statuses'),
        );
        $params['filter'] = array(
            'description' => __('Use WP Query arguments to modify the response; private query vars require appropriate authorization.'),
        );

        $taxonomies = wp_list_filter(get_object_taxonomies(get_post_types(array(), 'names'), 'objects'), array('show_in_rest' => true));
        foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
            $base = !empty($taxonomy->rest_base) ? $taxonomy->rest_base : $taxonomy->name;

            $params[$base] = array(
                'description'       => sprintf(__('Limit result set to all items that have the specified term assigned in the %s taxonomy.'), $base),
                'type'              => 'array',
                'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_parse_id_list',
                'default'           => array(),
            );
        }
        return $params;
    }

    /**
     * Validate whether the user can query private statuses
     *
     * @param  mixed             $value
     * @param  WP_REST_Request   $request
     * @param  string            $parameter
     *
     * @return WP_Error|boolean
     */
    public function validate_user_can_query_private_statuses($value, $request, $parameter)
    {
        if ('publish' === $value) {
            return true;
        }

        foreach ($request["type"] as $post_type) {
            $post_type_obj = get_post_type_object($post_type);
            if (!current_user_can($post_type_obj->cap->edit_posts)) {
                return new WP_Error('rest_forbidden_status', __('Status is forbidden'), array(
                    'status'    => rest_authorization_required_code(),
                    'post_type' => $post_type_obj->name,
                ));
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

To register the endpoint, you can use something like the following:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'init_wp_rest_multiple_post_type_endpoint');
function init_wp_rest_multiple_post_type_endpoint()
{
    $controller = new WP_REST_MultiplePostType_Controller();
    $controller->register_routes();
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks so much.

Comment: Agreed this is brilliant.

Comment: I haven't used this code in a while as my own use-case for this has disapeared. Does everything still work properly with the latest version of WordPress?

Comment: Yes this is working perfectly for me, querying 7 post types with a category filter and paginated.

Comment: Someone built a plugin based on this code: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-multiple-posttype/

Answer (score 2):

Someone built a plugin based on the Accepted Answer by Ruben Ray Vreeken:

https://github.com/elevati/wp-api-multiple-posttype

Worked like a charm for me.